# How to search and find a syntax error and then correct the syntax by adding to the string?

Tags: pandas, replace, dataset, locate

If the string in a row is missing the syntax or have uncorrect syntax, i would like to locate that row and edit/correct that syntax for sorting purposes.

What i've come up with so far:

```
df.loc[~df['Syntax'].str.contains('x')] = '1x'+ df['Syntax'].astype(str)
```

provides the error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable


df = pd.read_excel('raw_data')

df.loc[~df['Syntax'].str.contains('x')] = '1x'+ df['Syntax'].astype(str)

df.sort_values('Syntax', inplace = True)

print (df)
```

Item 3 is the typical syntax error:

```
Item    Syntax  Date
1   1x12    5/14/2019
2   4x16    5/14/2019
3   32  5/14/2019
4   3x10    5/14/2019
```

And what i want is to find those with number only and add "1x" in front of it. Output would look like:

```
Item    Syntax  Date
1   1x12    5/14/2019
2   4x16    5/14/2019
3   1x32    5/14/2019
4   3x10    5/14/2019
```

Comment: The only issue with your code is that you are trying to assign a Series to all the column, pick the specific column instead. df.loc[~df['Syntax'].str.contains('x'), 'Syntax'] = '1x' + df['Syntax']

Answer (score 2):

Using `np.where` with `str.contains`

```
df.Syntax=np.where(df.Syntax.str.contains('x'),df.Syntax,'1x'+df.Syntax)
df
Out[48]: 
   Item Syntax       Date
0     1   1x12  5/14/2019
1     2   4x16  5/14/2019
2     3   1x32  5/14/2019
3     4   3x10  5/14/2019
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `update` and `isnumeric`

```
df.update('1x' + df.Syntax[df.Syntax.str.isnumeric()])


Out[1460]:
   Item Syntax       Date
0     1   1x12  5/14/2019
1     2   4x16  5/14/2019
2     3   1x32  5/14/2019
3     4   3x10  5/14/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this possible :

```
n=df.Syntax.str.extract(r'(\d{1,}x)?(\d{1,})')
n[0] =n[0].fillna('1x')
df.Syntax=n[0]+n[1]
print(n)
print(df)
```

---

```
   Item Syntax       Date
0     1   1x12  5/14/2019
1     2   4x16  5/14/2019
2     3     32  5/14/2019
3     4   3x10  5/14/2019
    0   1
0  1x  12
1  4x  16
2  1x  32
3  3x  10
   Item Syntax       Date
0     1   1x12  5/14/2019
1     2   4x16  5/14/2019
2     3   1x32  5/14/2019
3     4   3x10  5/14/2019
```